# Rake db:populate error: undefined method file_changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, carrierwave, rake-task

Here is my rake task file:

```
namespace  :db do
    desc "fill database with sample data"
    task :populate => :environment do

     puts "populating with sample data"

     make_users

     make_companies

     make_products

     make_images

     make_commits

    end
    end


    def make_users

        100.times do |user|

           User.create!(first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
                        last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
                        email: Faker::Internet.email,
                            question_response: "ques"+(user).to_s,
                            device_id: 100,
                            company_name:"somecompany"+(user).to_s)
        end
    end


    def make_companies

         100.times do |company|

               name = Faker::Name.first_name
               rep_name = "example"+(company).to_s
               rep_designation = "example_desig"+(company).to_s
               company_large_logo = "example_lg"+(company).to_s
               company_small_logo ="example_sg"+(company).to_s
               company_social_contacts = "example_csc"+(company).to_s
               company_writeup = "example_wr"+(company).to_s
               website = "exampleCompany"+(company).to_s
               rep_image = "example_image"+(company).to_s
               active = 1
               average = 10


               Company.create!(name: name,
                               rep_name: rep_name,
                               rep_designation: rep_designation,
                               company_social_contacts: company_social_contacts,
                               company_large_logo: company_large_logo,
                               company_small_logo: company_small_logo,
                               company_writeup: company_writeup,
                               website:website,
                               rep_image: rep_image,
                               active:active,
                               average: average)
          end
    end


    def make_products


        companies=Company.all

        100.times do |product|  


            name = Faker::Name.name
                image_url = "some_image_url"+(product+1).to_s
            description = "some_description"+(product+1).to_s
            website = "some_website"+(product+1).to_s
            active = 0
            unlocked_time = "time"+(product+1).to_s
            company_id = companies.sample.id
            #aggregate = product+10


            companies.sample.products.create!(name: name,
                                              image_url: image_url,
                                              description: description,
                                                  website: website,
                                                  active: active,
                                                  unlocked_time: unlocked_time,
                                                  company_id: company_id,
                                                  aggregate: 0)  
        end
    end


    def make_commits
        users = User.all
        products = Product.all

        100.times do |commit|

                user_selected=users.sample
                product_selected=products.sample

                user_selected.commits.create!(product_id: product_selected.id,
                                                                  user_id: user_selected.id,
                                                                  estimate: commit*2,
                                                                  commit: commit+1)
        end
    end


    def make_images

        products = Product.all

        100.times do |image|
                products.sample.images.create!(product_id: products.sample.id,
                                                                           file: "sample_image#{image+1}")
        end
    end
```

When I run rake `db:populate` I am getting this stack trace error.  How can I fix this?

Stack trace:

```
     populating with sample data
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `file_changed?' for #<Product:0x0000010493e6f8>
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:249:in `store_previous_model_for_file'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__4010438894236454661__update__1959316297081505070__callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_update_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `update'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__4010438894236454661__save__1959316297081505070__callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:217:in `block in update_attributes'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/app/models/product.rb:61:in `aggregate_more'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/app/models/commit.rb:30:in `aggregate_commit'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `_run__2272083058160445442__save__1959316297081505070__callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:104:in `save!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `block in save!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:14:in `insert_record'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:436:in `block (2 levels) in create_record'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:344:in `add_to_target'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:434:in `block in create_record'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:149:in `block in transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:433:in `create_record'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:123:in `create!'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `create!'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:107:in `block in make_commits'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:102:in `times'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:102:in `make_commits'
    /Users/test/Launch/launch/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:16:in `block (2 levels)
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in main
    Tasks: TOP => db:populate
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am also using Carrier-wave gem for image uploads.

Comment: I've edited this for you, but for future reference always submit the code in question on site if at all possible.  Sending people to Pastebin, or some other secondary site, may turn people off to answering your question.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, might be a bug with carrierwave. I'm doing a more basic, straight forward update of a mode. Do you have a mount_uploader on Product?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging I've managed to get passed this error. You need to do a migration to add a field, which is used by the `mount_uploader`. For example:

```
class Product
  mount_uploader :my_image
end
```

requires a migration of:

add_column :products, :my_image, :string

To be fair, this is in the readme of [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). Hope it helps :)